# nodejs abort fetch in lambda AWS environment

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I managed to have a working abort controller in nodejs on a local environment, something as simple as this:

```
const signal = controller.signal;

setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 5000);

fetch(url, { signal }).then(response => {
  return response.text();
}).then(text => {
  console.log(text);
});
```

So I am able to abort the request after n seconds.It works without issues in local environment, however when deployed to AWS in a Lambda I endup with and error

`TypeError: Expected signal to be an instanceof AbortSignal`

After digging in the fetch module source it seems that this line is the culprit:

`!isAbortSignal(signal)`

From this function::

```
function isAbortSignal(signal) {
    const proto = signal && typeof signal === 'object' && Object.getPrototypeOf(signal);
    return !!(proto && proto.constructor.name === 'AbortSignal');
}
```

The `proto.constructor.name` in local is correct as "AbortSignal" while in AWS lambda it ends up being just 'a'.

I searched around but I could not find anything specific about why this is not working. Any tips on that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the *node-fetch* module? *fetch* and *AbortController* don't exist in native nodejs. You'll need to use the nodejs polyfill for each.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-abort-controller

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should be fixed in node-fetch v3 (currently in beta)

In my case, I'm using Webpack to bundle before uploading the code to AWS, after upgrading to 3.0.0-beta.4 it worked.

If you cant upgrade and using webpack try:

```
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          mangle: false,
          keep_classnames: true,
          keep_fnames: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
```

and if it doesn't work try to config `optimization.minimize` to `false`